# How to add custom (ex. golang) path to sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to build go project via `make`. Everything is ok until it goes to deploy in production.
The deploying user is not the owner so I have to use `sudo`. But with `sudo` system doesnt see go.

To reproduce the situation there's no need in using make, we can just use `go version`

I tried to use the current user environment like: `sudo -E go version` with no success.

Then tried to install go for the root. No success.

Finally tried to set golang path globally for all the profiles in `/etc/profile`. Still no luck.

I guess when it comes to the `sudo` system somehow skips profile settings. However, googling about it gave me nothing. Please, give me a hand of help!

Thanks in advance!

***UPD 1***
When `sudo go version`

sudo: go: command not found

When `sudo bash -c "type go"`

bash: line 0: type: go: not found

Output for `sudo -l` is:

```
Matching Defaults entries for deploy on host16-32:

    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User deploy may run the following commands on host16-32:

    (ALL : ALL) ALL

    (ALL) ALL
```

Comment: On my system go works fine for both users. Besides I wonder why you want to use go as root, it seems you have some strange misconfiguration. What error message do you receive when trying to execute `sudo go version`? May you please run `sudo bash -c "type go"` and add the output to your original post? PS please also add output of `sudo -l`

Comment: Where is `go` installed? What is the output of `type -a go` for the user who does see it? What operating system are you using? Do you control the Makefile? Can't you use  the full path there? Or will this be distributed to other systems you don't control?

Comment: @terdon the output is "go is /usr/local/go/bin/go", it is whr golang is installed. Yes, I can edit Makefile. Yes, I can, but I'd like to figure out what is wrong with sudo.

Comment: @paladin here you go

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769093/how-to-add-custom-ex-golang-path-to-sudo#comment1468306_769093), The go documentation say:

> Do not untar the archive into an existing /usr/local/go tree. This is known to produce broken Go installations.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.22.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Add the following line to your `/etc/profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

> Note: Changes made to a profile file may not apply until the next time you log into your computer.

[go install.](https://go.dev/doc/install)

Comment: I did it a bloody dozen times trying different recipes starting from go docs and ending with tricky installation howtos. Installation is OK, I can get `go version` as a user, I can't get it as `sudo` (however the root gets it successfully).